# C linked list Access violation

Tags: list, pointers, linked-list, access-violation

I have made this program with pointers and functions which is supposed to be a linked list. I keep getting "Access violation reading location 0xcdcdcded." in the last part below. I think it might be that I'm not initializing next but I'm new to pointers and don't know how to do that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
typedef struct temp 
{
    char name[20];
    char telephone[10];
    temp *next;
} node;


node* creation1 ()
{    
    node *NEW = NULL;
    NEW = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); 
    return NEW;
}

node* creation2 ()
{   
    node *start= NULL;
    node *NEW = creation1();
    start= NEW;
    return start;
}

node* creation3 ()
{    
    node *NEW = creation1();
    node *current = NULL;
    current=NEW;
    return current;
} 

void consult ()
{   
    node *NEW= creation1();
    node *start= creation2();
    node *current = creation3();
    int exit;
    printf("How many contacts do you wish to add? ");
    scanf("%i",&exit);

    for(int i=1; i<=exit; i++)
    {
        NEW = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        current->next=NEW;                 
        current = NEW; 
        fflush(stdin);
        puts("NAME: ");
        gets(NEW->name); 
        puts("TELEPHONE: ");
        gets(NEW->telephone);
        NEW->next=NULL;
    } 

    current=start->next;

    int i = 0;
    do 
    {
        i++;
        current = current->next; //this is where it stops and gives me the access reading violation
    }while (current != NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{  
    consult();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems like it's probably homework, I don't want to give too much away, but your basic problem is that you first create a start node with the line `node *start= creation2();`. At this point in execution, the value of `start->next` is garbage and could be anything.

Then, in your for-loop, the `start` node is not touched at all, meaning that `start->next` still could be anything.

Next, in the line `current=start->next;`, you are setting `current` to `start->next`'s garbage value.

And then finally in the line `current = current->next;` you are dereferencing the garbage value and are jumping to a random place in memory.

In general, if you have a pointer value (such as `start->next`), and you don't have a good value to set the pointer to when you create it, you should set it to `NULL`. Then, before dereferencing a value (using the `->` operator), you should check if the variable on the left-hand side of the `->` is equal to `NULL`, and if it is, then do not perform the `->` operation. Any more specific advice is really hard for me to give because there are no comments in your code to explain what is supposed to be happening.